# How to save information in array for session to recall php

Tags: php, arrays, session, cookies

So this is from a very bad PHP book. It assumes you already know how to do PHP and gives totally inapplicable examples for the questions it asks. I need to save the tasks to an array so when the page opens back up it shows the tasks you made previously. The web is almost devoid of any PHP examples beyond the extremely simple and extremely difficult.

```
<?php
$lifetime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 ;    
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, "/");
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['tasks'])) $_SESSION['tasks'] = array();

if (isset($_POST['tasklist'])) {
    $task_list = $_POST['tasklist'];
} else {
    $task_list = array();
}

$errors = array();

switch( $_POST['action'] ) {
    case 'add':
        $new_task = $_POST['newtask'];
        if (empty($new_task)) {
            $errors[] = 'The new task cannot be empty.';
        } else {
            $task_list[] = $new_task;
        }
        break;
    case 'delete':
             $task_index = $_POST['taskid'];
             unset($task_list[$task_index]);
            $task_list = array_values($task_list);
            break;
    }
```

task_list.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Task List Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Task List Manager</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">

    <!-- part 1: the errors -->
    <?php if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
    <h2>Errors</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($errors as $error) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- part 2: the tasks -->
    <h2>Tasks</h2>
    <?php if (count($task_list) == 0) : ?>
        <p>There are no tasks in the task list.</p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach($task_list as $id => $task) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $id + 1 . '. ' . $task; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <br />

    <!-- part 3: the add form -->
    <h2>Add Task</h2>
    <form action="." method="post" >
        <?php foreach($task_list as $task) : ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="tasklist[]" value="<?php echo $task; ?>"/>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add"/>
        <label>Task:</label>
        <input type="text" name="newtask" id="newtask" /> <br />
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Task"/>
    </form>
    <br />


    <!-- part 4: the delete form -->
    <?php if (count($task_list) > 0) : ?>
    <h2>Delete Task</h2>
    <form action="." method="post" >
        <?php foreach($task_list as $task) : ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="tasklist[]" value="<?php echo $task; ?>"/>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete"/>
        <label>Task:</label>
        <select name="taskid">
            <?php foreach($task_list as $id => $task) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <?php echo $task; ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <br />
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete Task"/>
    </form>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- end main -->
    </div><!-- end page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did only read the header ... use SESSIONS for this, not cookies.

Comment: So, store the current information in a serialized cookie (besides, you should not use (un)serialize on cookie data for security reasons). Better, just store a unique ID in the cookie, and get the data back from a database table with that ID.

Comment: You cán store the array in a session variable or cookie, but whenever the user decides to clear his cache, he will have lost his task list.
If you wish to follow this path, make sure that you fill your `$_SESSION['tasks']`-array with all of the tasks.

Comment: How do I save all the tasks to the array?

Comment: AS Marty McVly said, it's very unlikely that a user comes back to finish his submissions weeks later - so, this part of code seems to be very unimportant. More important is to keep the user stay on the website and completely enter his data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing new array in _SESSION after modify (switch with actions). Do it in this way:

```
$_SESSION['tasks'] = $task_list;
```

To view them:

```
foreach($_SESSION['tasks'] as $value) {
    //display task
}
```

Btw, this is **terrible** idea. You should use database. Some hostings blocks session_set_cookie_params and User will lost his data after clearing browser cache.

You should also call it like that:

```
session_set_cookie_params($time);
```

Second parameter is optional.

**More datailed example**

Core:

```
//session start etc
if(!isset($_SESSION['tasks'])) $_SESSION['tasks'] = array();
if(isset($_POST['action']) {
    switch($_POST['action']) {
        case 'add':
            if(isset($_POST['newtask']) && !empty($_POST['newtask']))
                $_SESSION['tasks'][] = $_POST['newtask'];
            break;
        case 'remove':
            if(isset($_POST['taskid']))
                unset($_SESSION['tasks'][$_POST['taskid']]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Display:

```
echo '<form method=post><input type=hidden name=action value=remove>';
foreach($_SESSION['tasks'] as $k => $v) {
    echo $v.'<br />Remove: <input type=submit name=taskid value='.$k.'>';
}
echo '</form>';
```

Add:

```
<form method=post>
<input type=hidden name=action value=add>
<input type=text name=newtask>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

Comment: I still dont get it. Seems like every way I try it I get errors.

Comment: I improved my answer. Check it.